# Send an image of product to paypal

Tags: paypal

I'm not sure if it's possible, please let me know if it is not.

Can you send an image of a product to the PayPal shopping cart? If you can how do you do this. My guess would be that it would be something like this.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="image" value="img/myProduct.jpg">
```

Comment: Why has this been marked down?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found:

Unfortunately with PayPal's Website Payments Standard there are no features or options to available to support what you have in mind.

With PayPal's Website Payments Standard, you're limited to changing the color scheme, displaying a business graphic logo (providing you have a Business Account), changing the text on the Note to Seller option box ("cn" variable) and changing the text on the "Return to Merchant" link ("cbt" variable).   That's it.

You may want to check out the features of some 3rd party shopping carts as there may be a few out there that have the features you are looking for.  Another option depending on your programming skills would be to develop your own mini-cart type application with the features you need.